# Are quadratic multi-stage optimization problems with quadratic constraints solvable by stochastic dual dynamic programming and SDDP.jl?

Tags: julia, stochastic-dual-dynamic-programming, sddp

I have a program with quadratic objective and constraints, and wanna utilize sddp.jl package in julia for solution.

Comment: Please post further questions on https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use a solver that supports quadratic objectives and constraints, and the problem is convex.

Comment: Is IPOPT able to solve convex QCQP problems?